# type of loops in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Please tell me the all kind of loops that we can use in SQL Server 2008. Example of each would be good.

Comment: What do you mean "types of loops"? Do you mean in TSQL procedural code such as `WHILE`? Or would a recursive CTE count as a loop? And what about a nested loops join?

Answer (score 6):

You should avoid loops when you can, try to find a set based approach. You'll get more performance that way.

Here's an article describing why:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/avoiding-cursors-with-sql-server-2005/412

If you really need loops:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/comparing-cursor-vs-while-loop-performance-in-sql-server-2008/1741