# How to perform a task repeatedly in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There is a SQL script with some  declared variables. I want to run this script for various sets of values of these variables and see the outputs. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you done any research on using a set-based approach? Or loops (which is the lesser-recommended route).

Comment: @Brian - can you tell me the technical term for "set based approach" so that I can search it easily in Google?

Comment: @sequel, what exactly have you tried?

Comment: @RandomUs1r - nothing really. Just searched google for looping. Was looking for other options  as well.

Comment: @sequel.lerner - +1 for showing initiative and that you are actively learning.

Comment: what are some sample values for the declared variables? Will the set method, or the cursor methods work for you detailed below? I've noticed you haven't accepted any answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a note:  this answer is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912346/type-of-loops-in-sql-server) but is a great resource for what you are asking.

More examples for set-based vs. procedural can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/03/30/procedural-versus-set-based-sql.aspx) and [here](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/34340/diff-between-cursor-based-approch-and-set-based.html).

And here is an actual example in SQL code:

```
DECLARE @someFlag INT
SET @someFlag = 0
WHILE (@someFlag <=5)
BEGIN
PRINT @someFlag 
SET @someFlag = @someFlag + 1
END
GO
```

Comment: can you tell me the technical term for "set based approach" so that I can search it easily in Google? The answer in the above post does not do that.

Comment: Post updated with some more links for you.  Please don't forget to upvote and accept which ever answer you find most helpful.

Comment: Please don't forget to add useful information to answers even though links can be used to reference external resources.

Comment: @Brian - Thanks for those links. I understood how to loop using an int. How do i execute the script for a different string in each iteration. example - for @ city = boston, run script. for @ city = new york, run script etc.

Comment: @sequel.learner - In the case of using a string, you may be better off researching stored procedures as was mentioned above.  When using strings, you have to be careful as they are a _value type_, meaning that to 'change' them, you are effectively 'adding' (concatenating) to the existing string.  This gets slower and slower the larger the string you work with gets.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the appropriate permissions to do it, you could set up the script as a stored procedure and then run the procedure multiple times.  Reference on how to do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926(v=sql.100).aspx

You don't have to make a permanent proc either, if you don't need it or want it in whatever database you're running it in, you can set it up as a temp proc instead.

So instead of CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_SomeProcedure AS ....
you would do CREATE PROCEDURE #usp_SomeProcedure

Your other option is to put your script into an nvarchar(max) variable and use that along with your other variables to run sp_executesql (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I would either use a Cursor or a While loop (preference would be the While). It would be something like this

```
DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 1

WHILE (@i <=10)
BEGIN    
   -- do whatever you need to do
   SET @i = @i + 1
END
```