# Loops in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops, foreach

I am just learning SQL and using 2008. I was wondering if there is a way to write a loop so that a query runs multiple times but changes a variable name.

For instance I would like to write a loop that runs a query and uses "Dawn" to select from a variety of fields with "Dawn" in the name and then output the results to tables with "Dawn" in their names. Then I would like to run the same thing again with "Day" and "Dusk" and "Night".

I could just rewrite the queries and substitute in the other words, but I'd like to use the opportunity to learn with this relatively low number of repeats.

Example of what I would like to do simplified way down:
`Dawn.Count`, `Day.Count`, etc. are column names.

```
FOR EACH LOOP
Var1=Dawn, Day, Dusk, Night

SELECT Var1.Count
FROM Table1
```

From looking at books and on the web, I can't find anything that will switch out variables names like that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: While not directly related, you might want to look at this when thinking of using loops in SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912346/type-of-loops-in-sql-server

Comment: It's useful technique to know, but the main thing to know about loops in sql, is try really hard not to.

Comment: Is `Dawn.Count` _literally_ the column name or are you trying to get a count of the values in the field `Dawn`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Since you are learning SQL, I would recommend that you start thinking of results using a **set-based approach** rather than a **iterative approach**. A `loop or a cursor`, though required at times, should be you last go-to approaches as they can be very resource intensive.

You can use a `WHILE` loop to iterate thru a record set

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE AS TABLE
(   
    id int,
    TIMEOFDAY VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE
SELECT 1, 'dawm'
union all
SELECT 2, 'day'
union all
SELECT 3, 'dusk'
union all
SELECT 4, 'night'


DECLARE @TIMEOFDAY varchar(30)

DECLARE @ID AS BIGINT
DECLARE @CNT AS BIGINT

SET @CNT = ISNULL((
            SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM @MYTABLE
            ), 0)
SET @ID = 1

    -- START OF LOOP
WHILE @ID <= @CNT
BEGIN
    SET @TIMEOFDAY = ISNULL((
                SELECT timeofday
                FROM @MYTABLE
                WHERE ID = @ID
                ), '')
            -- DO STUFF WITH YOUR @TIMEOFDAY VALUE
    PRINT @TIMEOFDAY
    PRINT @ID

    --------------
    SET @ID = @ID + 1
END
```